# Grouped WPF ListView Styling issue with margin

Tags: .net, wpf, listview

There is a tiny **margin on the left side** in the style when using the **grouping** functionality of the ListView in WPF.

**Sample of ListView with grouping problem (margin):**

[image: ListView, group by name]

**Sample of ListView without grouping (want same style of item in grouped list):**

[image: ListView, without grouping]

**Question:**

How to remove the margin/padding? The (selected) item in the grouped list should fill the same space as in the ungrouped list.

**Update:**

```
            <ListView Margin="20,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsView}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="data:Item">
                                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5,5,5" />
                                    <Separator  />
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="data:Item">
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Try defining a `Style` for the [`ItemsControl.GroupStyle` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Already did... margin (Set Margin="0") but is still there for the grouped item. What exactly needs to be set?

Comment: It could be `Padding`... the best way to find out is to colour the `Background` of the various internal controls differently. That way, you'll be able to see which control is taking up the space and act accordingly.

Comment: @Sheridan Padding of what control? this didn't help, I have no idea which object to style. It is not a part of the DataItemTemplate and not a part GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate.

Comment: Then show the relevant XAML that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: @Sheridan: Added XAML. The TextBlock Margin is the same for both appearances of the view (grouped and not grouped) but it looks different (see screenshots before).

Comment: I think that you might need to use the `GroupStyle.ContainerStyle` property. Take a look at the [How to: Group Items in a ListView That Implements a GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754027(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When grouping is used in a CollectionViewSource (I'm assuming you are using one), the,  Groups will be visualized by a GroupItem. The default style of a GroupItem looks like this (obtained with StyleSnooper):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" />
                    <ItemsPresenter Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see, there is a Margin on the ItemsPresenter. A solution is to create your own style for the GroupItem, and remove the Margin on the ItemsPresenter, and set the GroupStyle.ContainerStyle to use this style.

Comment: Don't know why MS use 5,0,0,0 as default.